# How to wrap an existing element with another one in jQuery?

Tags: jquery, html

How can I create a `<div>` surrounding an existing `<div>`.

My code is as follows:

```
<div id="test">
  <h2>Greetings</h2>
  <p>Test</p>
  <div class="inner">Hello</div>
  <p>Test</p>
  <div class="inner">Goodbye</div>
</div>
<div id="test2">
  <h2>Greetings</h2>
  <p>Test</p>
  <div class="inner">Hello</div>
  <p>Test</p>
  <div class="inner">Goodbye</div>
</div>

<script>
  $("#test").before('<div class="test3">');
  $("#test2").after('</div>');
</script>
```

But it seems that it cannot insert a `<div>` without an end tag. So how to achieve that?

Comment: You might want to wrap your code in $(function(){ //code here }); so that it only executes it ones the page is fully loaded

Comment: I have a dynamic list with an iterator. And i need to insert 3 items per div. :(

Comment: Kyoka, no need for that as the html comes before the script.

Comment: What are these items ? Are they divs ?

Comment: 1 item == 1 div... so for 3 items == 3 divs. I need to insert all 3 divs into 1 big div container

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use the [`.wrapAll()` <sup>doc</sup>](http://api.jquery.com/wrapall/) method

```
$('#test, #test2').wrapAll('<div class="test3">');
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use the [.wrap()](http://api.jquery.com/wrap/) API call which will wrap existing HTML with a new element.

Comment: this will wrap each of the selected items.. so it will put a different container around each of the items.. `wrapAll` is the one needed in this case..

Answer (score 3):

jQuery wraps the native DOM API, which works with complete HTML elements.

You cannot insert half of a tag.

Instead, you should build a complete node by creating a detached `$('<div />')`, appending multiple elements to it, then adding the entire tree to the DOM.

Comment: is there a workaround? or how can i insert three items inside a div dynamically?

Comment: This really does nothing to answer the question.

Answer (score 1):

ok, use that:

```
<script>
       var inner=$("#test");
       var outer=$('<div class="outer"></div>');
       outer.html(inner.html());
       inner=outer;
</script>
```

Comment: Shoudn't you just remove your answer then?

Answer (score 1):

This is what you should do:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
    $('<div class="test3"></div>')
        .insertBefore($('#test'))
        .append($('#test'))
        .append($("#test2"));
}
</script>
```